# How to add to the button image below text from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, button, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have a quiz fragment with answers as buttons. I am using Firebase Storage (for images). I would like to add images for answers below the text.

Is there some way to do it with Glide (or anything else) to

1. get image by URL from Storage (done)
2. set image below the text in button (like in setDrawableBottom but from Storage)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

```
Glide.with(view).load(questionModels.get(i-1).getAnswer_img())
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                            resource.setBounds(0,0, resource.getIntrinsicWidth() * 4, resource.getIntrinsicHeight()* 4);
                            option1Btn.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, resource);
                        }
                    });
```

where
`Glide.with(view).load(questionModels.get(i-1).getAnswer_img()` is my getter for getting URL for the answer image,
`option1Btn` is my Button that I defined earlier as

```
option1Btn = view.findViewById(R.id.answer1Button);
```